# Login loop in Centos 5.5

Tags: linux, login, centos-5

A strange problem occurred after a power shortage. The server works and I'm able to log in as root from SSH, but not able to log in directly (with keyboard connected directly to the machine).

This is what I see in var/log/secure:

```
Sep 25 13:28:30 theserver login: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
Sep 25 13:28:30 theserver login: ROOT LOGIN ON tty1
Sep 25 13:28:30 theserver login: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user root
```

So I created a new user (`useradd ...`, `passwd ...`). Same thing - session opened and immediate session close... WTF?

Also some services are not starting automatically, but this might be unrelated - the server have not been restarted for a while ;-). All service that do start automatically seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As seems the problem was related to SELinux Policy corruption. It also affected cron and other services, but I'm not sure if this was directly related. Not sure how the corruption occured, maybe some hardware failure or something after power failure...

Anyway reinstalling SELinux Policy solved all this things.